# Swift - Search in array if contains string and append to another array

Tags: arrays, swift, search, indexing, contains

I have an array:

```
let arr = ["Ivan Ivanov", "Bogdan Bogdanov", "Georgi Milchev", "Bogdan Petkov", "Vladimir Zahariev"]
let name = "Bogdan"
```

Search if array contains(name) and append the result to the new array without loop.
So new array have to be ["Bogdan Bogdanov", "Bogdan Petkov"]

Trying with: `if arr.contains(where: {$0 == name}) { newArray.append($0) }`

but it's not working. Error: `Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
let res = arr.compactMap { $0.contains(name) ? $0.components(separatedBy: " ").last! : nil  }
```

Comment: How to remove `name`? I need only family name to stay. Is there a code without looping the new array?

Comment: here `"Bogdan Bogdanov"`  you need it `"Bogdanov"` only ?

Comment: Yes, please I need only "Bogdanov".

Comment: Can you give me website to learn this shortcuts ? Where did you learn it ?

Comment: Bogdan take a look at the Swift Language guide. E.g. for shorthand notation see https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html section named "Shorthand Argument Names". It's a nice read/reference.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov your guide to array https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array